# How to prevent minmax spinner tag from allowing decimal inputs?

Tags: primefaces, spinner

`<p:spinner id="x" min="1" max="999" step="1" value="#{bean.val}">
</p:spinner>`

This code allows decimal inputs. I don't want decimal inputs. How can I do that?

Comment: I cannot enter decimals in te showcase, what is the type of your propery htat backs the input?

Answer (score 0):

Just add decimalPlaces="0".

```xml
<p:spinner id="x" min="1" max="999" step="1" value="#{bean.val}" decimalPlaces="0">
```

See source code: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/spinner/SpinnerBase.java#L48

Comment: The showcase does not have this, yet I'm not able to enter decimals in the min/max example. The backingbean having an int might play a role too... Maybe refer to this in your answer as well.

Comment: is there any js or css for this ? i dont want to use java

Comment: also I tried using this. I created the same extendable class and added decimalPlaces in my jsf spinner tag but nothing happened.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue.  Can you provide a reproducible example?